# Finding a Liapunov function for a two dimensional system.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

I need to find a Liapunov function to determine the stability of a point. Given the system $$\frac{du}{dt} = v, \ \frac{dv}{dt} = -u - u^4$$
Find a suitable Liapunov function to determine the stability of the point $(0,0)$.

Orginally, I was thinking of a Liapunov function $$V = au^2 + buv + cv^2.\ a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$$
However, filling this in gives $$\dot{V} = V_u \frac{du}{dt} + V_v \frac{dv}{dt}$$
$$\dot{V} = (2au + bv)\cdot v + (bu + 2cv)\cdot(-u - u^4)$$
$$\dot{V} = a\cdot(2uv) + b \cdot (v^2-u^2-u^5)+c\cdot(-2uv-2uv^4)$$
And I cannot find any constant $a,b,c$ such that either $\dot{V} \leq 0$, $\dot{V} < 0$, $\dot{V} > 0$ holds, but I am unable to.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is a particular case of an [Hamiltonian system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_system) so for example the Hamiltonian:
$$H(u,v)=v^2+\frac{1}{2} u^2+\frac{1}{5} u^5$$
is such that:
$$ \frac{d }{dt}H(u(t),v(t)) =0$$.

Comment: Hmm okay good to know. However, reading Wikipedia did not guide me to a Liapunov function. Can you help me a little further? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why isn't $H$ a good Liapunov function ?

Comment: A I think $V = \frac{1}{2}v^2 + \frac{1}{2}u^2 + \frac{1}{5}u^5$ is a Lyapunov function, resulting in $\dot{V} = 0$, thus $(0,0)$ is asymptotically stable, right? Thanks!

Comment: No, $(0, 0)$ is **NOT** asymptotically stable (in Hamiltonian systems there are no asymptotically stable equilibria).